# How can i reduce memory usage of Scikit-Learn Vectorizers?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

TFIDFVectorizer takes so much memory ,vectorizing 470 MB of 100k documents takes over 6 GB , if we go 21 million documents it will not fit 60 GB of RAM we have.

So we go for HashingVectorizer but still need  to know how to distribute the hashing vectorizer.Fit and partial fit does nothing so how to work with Huge Corpus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to use the [HashingVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#vectorizing-a-large-text-corpus-with-the-hashing-trick) when fitting models on large dataset.

The `HashingVectorizer` is data independent, only the parameters from `vectorizer.get_params()` are important. Hence (un)pickling `HashingVectorizer instance should be very fast.

The vocabulary based vectorizers are better suited for exploratory analysis on small datasets.

Comment: Verygood , i found this out : http://t.co/12cFDYlTil and testing. Can we use Unsupervised Learning (KMeans) ?

Comment: On TFIDFVectorizers we can use Randomized PCA for plotting  , but HashingVectorizer output is different right? How can we do Scatterplot on that?

Comment: Why would it be different? RandomizedPCA can take any sparse matrix as input, what ever the way it was generated.

Comment: If you want to do out-of-core unsupervised learning (clustering) you should use MiniBatchKMeans instead of KMeans. Only the former has a `partial_fit` method.

Comment: We managed to get those List of HashingVectorizers to work with MBK , but when visualized Resulting Clusters are about 30% different vs TFIDFVectorizer.

Comment: `HashingVectorizer` does not do IDF weighting. That might be the cause of your problem. You could try to pipeline a `TfidfTransformer` to do the IDF re-weighting on the output of the `HashingVectorizer` manually.

Comment: Thanks we are testing using TfidfTransformer . I sent you email with multiple links of visualizations screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

One way to overcome the inability of HashingVectorizer to account for IDF is to index your data into elasticsearch or lucene and retrieve termvectors from there using which you can calculate Tf-IDF.