# How to efficiently serialize a scikit-learn classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, scikit-learn

What's the most efficient way to serialize a scikit-learn classifier?

I'm currently using Python's standard Pickle module to serialize a [text classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526579/use-scikit-learn-to-classify-into-multiple-categories), but this results in a monstrously large pickle. The serialized object can be 100MB or more, which seems excessive and takes a while to generate and store. I've done similar work with Weka, and the equivalent serialized classifier is usually just a couple of MBs.

Is scikit-learn possibly caching the training data, or other extraneous info, in the pickle? If so, how can I speed up and reduce the size of serialized scikit-learn classifiers?

```
classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())),
])
```

Comment: Did you use the protocol -1 in cPickle? That often makes an uncanny difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large text datasets, use the hashing trick: replace the `TfidfVectorizer` by a `HashingVectorizer` (potentially stacked with a `TfidfTransformer` in the pipeline): it will be much faster to pickle as you won't have to store the vocabulary dict any more as discussed recently in this question:

[How can i reduce memory usage of Scikit-Learn Vectorizers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536394/how-can-i-reduce-memory-usage-of-scikit-learn-vectorizers/17536682)

Comment: Thanks. That and using joblib reduced size by about 20-30%. Not huge but decent.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [joblib.dump](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html) and pass in a compression. I noticed my classifier pickle dumps reducing by a factor of ~16 using option compress=3.